# How to specify which wallet address to deploy contract with

Tags: web3js, truffle

When deploying with Truffle how do you specify which wallet address to deploy with? I know if you're using web3 you can specify `web3.eth.defaultAccount` but how would I do this Truffle? I read somewhere to adjust your `truffle.js` file and add a `from` but it spits an error for me. How would truffle know which address I'm using to interact with it, e.g. me using MetaMask.

Comment: Can you paste your truffle.js file, the error, and tell us which network you want to deploy to ?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy to testrpc. I'm just wondering how you can get the address that's interacting with a deployed contract

Answer (score 3):

By default, truffle uses the first account but in `truffle.js` you can specify the account address in the `from` property:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', 
      from: '0x0c439ff0170Ab7d7Ef55f2993554eede7321c9b7'
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to deploy to a network other than localhost then you need to import a wallet provider and pass it your mnemonic.

Here's an example where the mnemonic is read from an environment variable and the provider is set to rinkeby testnet:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')

const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" 
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://rinkeby.infura.io'),
      network_id: '*',
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 25000000000
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to specify the account in case of HDWallet?

Comment: use the `from` option in the migration file, ex: `deployer.deploy(A, {from: "0x...."})` https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations

Answer (score 0):

The 'from' field didn't work for me, instead, I went to my truffle-config.js file and inserted an additional third parameter for `new HDWalletProvider`.
The details are elaborated on the [trufflesuite sub repo](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider)

```
ropsten: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://<TESTNET NAME>.infura.io/v3/<INFURA-PROJECT-ID>`,2), //2 here means that truffle will use the wallet address at index 2 when deploying. If you have 3 wallets on MetaMask and you want to use the third wallet, the index should be 2. 
  network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
  gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
  confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},
```